# Copy merged cells VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge, copy

I am trying to copy entire rows onto a new worksheet, but only copy those rows where a childs age is above 20.

I have not yet written the If statements to select these rows, but have written code to import the data and fill in various columns in order to get the 20th birthday from the birth date.

My problem is that the cells in the columns that are on the imported worksheet are merged. This is merged because one person may have more than one child, so in this case, the cells regarding the parent are merged. It won't let me copy the merged cells.

For now I'm just trying to work out how to copy the entire sheet just so I know how to copy merged cells, before doing the If statement.

This is what I have so far (bold bit at bottom is where I'm trying to copy merged cells. I'm getting an error on the line with ActiveSheet.Range("**").MergeArea.Copy

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportActiveList()
Dim FileName As String
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim ActiveListWB As Workbook

    Set WS2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
                                               Title:="Select Active List to Import", _
                                               MultiSelect:=False)

    If FileName = "False" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Set ActiveListWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
    End If

    Set WS1 = ActiveListWB.Sheets("Page1-1")

    WS1.UsedRange.Copy WS2.Range("A1")

    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub


Sub CalculateBirthday()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("A5:AA291").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$AA$291").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="Child"

    Range("AB5") = "Today's Age Year/Month"
    Range("AB7:AB" & lastrow).Formula = "=DATEDIF(RC[-2],TODAY(),""Y"") & "" Years, "" & DATEDIF(RC[-2],TODAY(),""YM"") & "" Months """
    Columns("AB:AB").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Range("AC5") = "Today's Age Year Only"
    Range("AC7:AC" & lastrow).Formula = "=DATEDIF(RC[-3],TODAY(),""Y"")"
    Columns("AC:AC").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Range("AD5") = "Child 20th Birthday"
    Range("AD7:AD" & lastrow).Formula = "=DATE(YEAR(R[-1]C[-4])+20, MONTH(R[-1]C[-4]),DAY(R[-1]C[-4]))"
    Columns("AD:AD").EntireColumn.AutoFit


    ActiveSheet.Range("A5:AA291").MergeArea.Copy    'copies the merged cells 
    Sheet2.Range("A1").PasteValues       ' pastes what was copied into A1 on Sheet 2 and any merged cells**

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, the bold bit didn't work. It's the last 2 lines I'm after. Basically I just want to copy merged cells onto a new sheet.

Comment: Merged cells = nightmare to work with, every. single. time.  Is there any way you can adjust your workbook so that it doesn't have merged cells? Generally speaking it's always bad practice to use merged cells.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not my worksheet so unfortunately I had no say in whether they come to me already merged.

I did unmerge them, trying this both before and after filtering on "Child", but this deleted some of the information unfortunately.

Comment: Yeh I just tried again. Unmerging them just deletes the information that was merged :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("A5").Copy
sheet2.Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for the line starting with Selection :(

Comment: It's actually the Paste:= that seems to be causing the issue.

Comment: try now @dogmum ... I fixed the code formatting. And **please** just use `sheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. No need for `.Select`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I get the error 'Select method of Range class failed'.

If I delete he .Select from the sheet2.range bit then I get an 'Invalid use of property' error :(

Comment: try :                                                                                                               Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I see what I've done now. Next step is for me to get it to copy rows where the child is over 20. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Ah ok. Now when I try to make it include an entire row instead of just cell A5, I get the 'Can't do this to a merged cell; error again :(